# Is it possible to add custom metadata to .class files?

Tags: java, debugging, bytecode

We have used liquibase at our company for a while, and we've had a continuous integration environment set up for the database migrations that would break a job when a patch had an error.

An interesting "feature" of that CI environment is that the breakage had a "likely culprit", because all patches need to have an "author", and the error message shows the author name.

If you don't know what liquibase is, that's ok, its not the point.

The point is: having a **person** name attached to a error is really good to the software development proccess: **problems get addressed way faster**.

So I was thinking: Is that possible for Java stacktraces?

Could we possibly had a stacktrace with peoples names along with line numbers like the one below?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hibernate.tuple.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:372:john)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3121:mike)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:232:bob)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:173:bob)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:87:bob)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:862:john)
```

That kind of information would have to be pulled out from a SCM system (like performing "svn blame" for each source file).

Now, forget about trashing the compilation time for a minute: Would that be even possible?
To add metadata to class files like that?

Comment: Why would you put this in a class file? Having this in an external system would probably be a better idea?

Comment: I doubt the traces would be relevant, the lines throwing a NullPointerException is rarely the line responsible for the error (and the author is certainly not the one to blame). The error occurs because the data processed by the code was not properly sanitized, and when it blows it's too late (and too far from the point in the code that should be fixed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally such feature can be implemented on top of the version control system. You need to know revision of your file in your version control system, then you can call [blame/annotate](http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html#browse) command to get information on who has changed each individual line. You don't need to store this info into the class file, as long as you can identify revision of each class you deploy (e.g. you only deploy certain tag or label).

If you don't want to go into the version control when investigating stack trace, you could store line annotation info into the class file, e.g. using class post processor during your build that can add a custom annotation at the class level (this is relatively trivial to implement using [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)). Then logger that prints stack trace could read this annotation at runtime, similarly to [showing jar versions](http://macstrac.blogspot.com/2008/09/better-stack-traces-in-java-with-log4j.html).

Comment: Great answer Eugene. Very useful links too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In principle you can add custom information to .class files (there's and attribute section where you can add stuff). You will have to write your own compiler/compiler extension to do so. There is no way to add something to your source code that then will show up in the class file.
You will also have major problems in practice:

1. The way stack-traces a built/printed is not aware of anything you add to the class file. So if you want this stuff printed like you show above, you have to hack some core JDK classes.
2. How much detail do you want? The last person who committed any change to a given file? That's not precise enough in practice, unless files are owned by a single developer.
3. Adding "last-committed-by" information at a finer granularity, say per method, or even worse, per line will quickly bloat your class file (and class files are limited in size to 64K)

As a side note, whether or not blaming people for bugs helps getting bugs fixed faster strongly depends on the culture of the development organization. Make sure you work in one where this helps before you spend a lot of time developing something like this.

Comment: The class files are not limited to 64K. But the methods are, and this process could indeed trigger "code too large" errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jochen. 
I don´t really plan on actually doing it.
It was just a "what if" that came to me, and I wanted to see what the smart mind here would think about it.

Also, for that purpose, I think @srs2012 is probably right - 
this kind of info would be better off the .class files and then one could have some kind of "post-processing" done on the stack trace.

Comment: Anyway, knowing that it might be possible to add custom information to .class files (I´m not talking about annotations) sounds interesting.
That sort of thing could have other practical applications.
Can you point to some documentation that says more about the subject?

Comment: Downvoted, because this answer is making several invalid points.

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov Someone already spotted my mistake with the 64K limit for methods instead of classes. What are the other invalid points I made?

Comment: "There is no way to add something to your source code that then will show up in the class file" is not true (e.g. you could use annotations). Then you don't have to hack some core JDK classes (see my answer for an example), and it won't bloat class files (the data is reasonably small). Though I almost agree with your point #2, yet for your last note, the person who's code failed may know best what is it about and probably the best person to investigate issue regardless of blame. Didn't meant to be a smart ass, but it seemed like enough for a downvote. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Although, technically I have to point out that your example assumes that using a specialized logger is ok for him. I was much more narrowly answering his question. But you are right, nitpicking here isn't going to get us anywhere. He seems to be happy with the more involved solution you propose :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to add add custom information to your class files using [annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html) in the source code. I don't know how you would put that information reliably in the stack trace, but you could create a tool to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

As @theglauber correctly pointed out , you can use annotations to add custom metadata. Althougth i am not really sure you if you cant retrieve that information from your database implementing beans and decorating your custom exceptions manager.